# .HTACCESS - remove after part of the url

Tags: .htaccess

**Hi everybody,**

I moved the website from http to https. Then I went to Google search and visited the page url. However, instead of accessing the normal Url:

**https://example.com/handbook-of-neurosurgery**

Google gives me another link:

https://example.com/handbook-of-neurosurgery**?name_id=handbook-of-neurosurgery**

How can I remove the excess of the url with .htaccess?

Thank you very much for your help !

**My .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ /download.php?name_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} 

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule to remove the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name_id=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Full .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ /download.php?name_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name_id=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```

Let me know how that works.

Comment: Great, it worked. I am extremely thankful for your support!

Comment: Great and No problem. Please accept the answer clicking the check mark, since it worked for you.